# Swift 3 UITableViewAction error Missing argument for parameter rawValue in call

Tags: swift

I have the following code4 which worked in Swift 2 but does not work on upgrading the code to Swift 3 / Xcode 8.2

Error: `Missing argument for parameter rawValue in call`

Here is my problem code. The error is triggered at line 2.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    return [UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle(), title: "Remove", handler: { (_, _) -> Void in
    //        return [UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle(), title: "Remove", handler: { (_, _) -> Void in
        self.tableView(self.shoppingCartTableView, commit: .delete, forRowAt: indexPath)
    })]
}
```

Comment: First Google hit for "UITableViewRowAction swift 3" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableViewRowActionStyle is enum.

Code below should work:

```
UITableViewRowActionStyle.default
```

or just

```
.default
```